# How to respawn after collision? (Unity2D)

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I'm making a game and I need to get my player to respawn at the recent checkpoint when they touch a spike called 'Enemy' I haven't added my checkpoints yet but I'm just calling them 'Checkpoint1, Checkpoint2' u get the point (idk if that makes a difference I'm a noob) how would I code this? if u can please give me the full code as I will get confused otherwise. Thanks

Comment: Here is a tutorial that might help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ofCLJsSUom0

Answer (score 0):

you can either give the spike a tag or layer (both work)

then in the player script use OnCollisionEnter

[for 2D games](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html)

[for 3D games](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html)

then write an if statement to check if the collider's tag is the same as the desired tag, then it'll call a Respawn() method

if you want me to write the code just reply